# Pandas subtract all values from one value, move to next value and repeat

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

I have a df with two columns 'a' and 'b'

```
[a] [b]
11  100
2   100
10  100
```

What I need is an extra column 'c', which represents following calculation:

((11-2) + (11-10)) / 100

((2-11) + (2-10)) / 100

((10-11) + (10-2)) / 100

```
[a] [b]    [c]
11  100    0.1
2   100   -0.17
10  100    0.07
```

It should be highly dynamic, so the row count of [a] can differ. Speed is also a concern thats why I want to avoid for loops.

I tried to use .apply() and .pivot() to get it in an easy format to just call sub(), but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution rewrite to pandas:

Use [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mul.html), [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html), 
[`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html) and [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html), for `length` of `DataFrame` the fastest is `len(df.index)`

```
df['c'] = df.a.mul(len(df.index)).sub(df.a.sum()).div(df.b)
print (df)
    a    b     c
0  11  100  0.10
1   2  100 -0.17
2  10  100  0.07
```

It works, because:

```
((11-2) + (11-10))
```

is same as:

```
(2 * 11) - (2 + 10)
```

and same as:

```
(3 * 11) - (2 + 10 + 11)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll give a numpy example. For

```
>>> a = numpy.array([11, 2, 10])
>>> b = numpy.array([100, 100, 100])
```

you can do

```
>>> c = (len(a) * a - sum(a)) / b
```

Similar for a pandas data frame.

Comment: @Michael2016 - no problem, it is ok.